# Ecto - how to make assoc_constraint return the same error as validate_required?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Let's say I have a model `Post` which `belongs_to` `Category`:

```
defmodule MyApp.Post do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "posts" do
    field :title, :string
    belongs_to :category, MyApp.Category
  end

  def changeset(model, params) do
    model
    |> cast(params, [:title, :category_id)
    |> validate_required([:title, :category_id])
    |> assoc_constraint(:category)
  end
end
```

The problem is: if I don't pass `category_id` to params, the changeset error key is: `category_id`, but on `assoc_constraint` invalidation (if category isn't exist), I have `category` key. It's a little bit contrintuitive for me - because the problem is actually the same - there is no category for post. How can I deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this that I could find after reading through Ecto's source is to give the name you want in the error as the field to `assoc_constraint`, and then override the constraint name yourself. The default name for belongs_to constraint is `#{table name}_#{column in table}_fkey` ([source](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/97d75cef7f665f268a371ef56ea444483b819a5a/lib/ecto/changeset.ex#L1719)).

Edit: We might as well use `foreign_key_constraint` if we're passing the `:name` ourselves as that's the only thing `assoc_constraint` does that `foreign_key_constraint` doesn't. I've updated the code below.

Migration:

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateComment do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:comments) do
      add :post_id, references(:posts, on_delete: :nothing)
      timestamps()
    end
    create index(:comments, [:post_id])
  end
end
```

Model:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:post_id])
  |> validate_required([:post_id])
  |> foreign_key_constraint(:post_id, name: :comments_post_id_fkey)
end
```

Demo:

```
iex(1)> Comment.changeset(%Comment{}, %{}).errors
[post_id: {"can't be blank", []}]
iex(2)> Comment.changeset(%Comment{}, %{post_id: 999}).errors
[]
iex(3)> {:error, changeset} = Comment.changeset(%Comment{}, %{post_id: 999}) |> Repo.insert; changeset.errors
[post_id: {"does not exist", []}]
iex(4)> Comment.changeset(%Comment{}, %{post_id: 1}) |> Repo.insert
{:ok,
 %MyApp.Comment{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "comments">,
  id: 1, inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-07-29 06:25:24>,
  post: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :post is not loaded>,
  post_id: 1, updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-07-29 06:25:24>}}
```